# httpd block access for all file types in a directory but allow access to a single file.

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

inside my site i have a directory  /here/is/the/dir/path

i want to allow access to a single file in a subdirectory 
         example:    test/testfile.xml 
but want to deny access to a list of other files (jsp, class, jar, xml )

i have this which i want to place in httpd.conf

```
    <Directory /here/is/the/dir/path >

    <FilesMatch "test.xml">
    Order Allow,Deny 
    Allow from All 
    Deny from None 
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "+\.(jsp|class|jar|xml)">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

    </Directory>
```

is this the correct way to write this? is there a way to combine my two file match statements into a single statement ?

Comment: i guess i should add the <directory> stanza and the second filematch is already in place and is blocking access to the files as expected.  I want to allow access to one file  so added the  first filematch in my snippet (above)

but i'm not sure if this is the correct way or if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: if it's just a single file in a subdirectory, yes, you should add the directory and the FilesMatch statement in it for the exact file. But even if your current config is a bit more generic, it is correct and you shouldn't worry about making it better, and most importantly, it makes sense to you, which is what really matters.

Comment: thanks @ezra-s it is in place and working as expected. I'm not exactly sure how to close a question with no answer. should i just post an answer and accept it ?

Comment: yes, answer yourself so it does not show up as unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the stated method has been tested and is working.